# How to avoid the fixed footer overlapping with the vertical scroll bar appears between header and footer

Tags: html, css

I have below example where the footer is at the bottom and it overlaps with the vertical scroll bar.

I have some pages where the vertical scroll bar would not be there (the inner content would be less). pages with no vertical scroll bar have no issues but pages with vertical scroll bar would have overlapping footer. So How to make footer display works properly irrespective of the vertical scroll bar.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZgKaL#0)

---

Or view the demo below:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  color: white;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 363px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 1px;
  width: 1557px;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#content-inner {
  height: 844px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
footer {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 5px solid green;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSS - Width</title>


</head>

<body>
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content-inner">
      scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>content outside
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>scrollable content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>End
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>Actual End

    </div>
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the footer fades away after some time, this would create extra space by giving margin-bottom. the thing is the footer is added dynamically like a widget to any app.

Comment: I  want to give the footer item has an widget (generic), the footer dynamically fades in and fades out using javascript.
the applications where the footer widget is included may or may not have vertical scroll bar between header and footer. footer should be independent of the application design where it is being included

Answer (score 2):

I quite like this solution:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .text-muted {
   margin: 20px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Check it out in code-pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVbbaw

---

Edit:
New codepen with updates as asked in comments below. It will now remove margin on body and content div, so that height of content fills the empty space of where the footer was located: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZEYyO

Comment: the footer fades away after some time, this would create extra space by giving margin-bottom. the thing is the footer is added dynamically like a widget to any app.

Comment: One issue here, Page has to be refreshed to get the margin bottom applied

Comment: You could do it with a bit javascript... I've added a button that removes the footer style and content. In here you can do whatever you want, whenever you want. Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNzEab

Comment: This is the code i have in my app,  i am trying to update the margin-bottom to footer height  on page load and trying to hide the footer as well as setting margin-bottom to 0px, It only works after i open the developer console , only then changes gets reflected. on loading the page also the margin-bottom which i am setting through jQuery is not getting applied, it may work in codepan but i do not know the issue in my app. link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxgqZa

Comment: I understand... Well there's actually just two minor fixes you have to do in your fadefooter method: 1: you want to first hide the footer (so that you don't need to think about that one anymore).  Then 2: you actually want to remove the margin-bottom on BOTH the body and the content div. Check out my new pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZEYyO NB: Added the pen to my answer also! :)

Answer (score 0):

give margin bottom or padding bottom to #content-inner.....

```
#content-inner{margin-bottom: 110px}
```

margin-bottom = (footer height + some extra pixels)....

Comment: the footer fades away after some time, this would create extra space by giving margin-bottom. the thing is the footer is added dynamically like a widget to any app.

Comment: I have applications where scroll bar appears after header, header occupies full width.